# Resolving Git conflicts with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparative-review, ecmascript-6

## Challenge:

Resolve git conflict by `resolveGitConflict(linesArray, resolveMode)`, where

`linesArray` is an array of strings

Example:

```
[
    "context1", 
    "context2", 
    "<<<<<<<", 
    "my changes1", 
    "=======", 
    "their changes1",
    ">>>>>>>",
    "context3",
    "context4",
    "<<<<<<<", 
    "my changes2", 
    "=======", 
    "their changes2",
    ">>>>>>>",
    "context5",
    "context6"
]
```

#### resolveMode -  a string indicate:

- m: Keep only current branch's changes
- t: Keep only other branch's changes
- tm: Keep both changes, but put other branch's changes before current branch's changes
- mt - Keep both changes, but put other branch's changes after current branch's changes
- none - Keep no changes

## Review

We have three solutions for that challenge. Please compare  all of them and tell which one is better.

#### Solution 1

```
const resolveGitConflict = (linesArray, resolveMode, t = []) =>
  linesArray.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(
    t.length ?
      c === '>>>>>>>' ?
        (c = [].concat(resolveMode[0] ? t.splice(+(resolveMode[0] === 't'), 1)[0].concat(resolveMode[1] ? t[0] : []) : [])) &&
        (t = []) && c
      : c === '=======' ? t[1] = [] : t[+!!t[1]].push(c) && []
    : c === '<<<<<<<' ? t[0] = [] : [c]
  ), [])
```

#### Solution 2

```
function resolveGitConflict(linesArray, mode) {
    var [changes, curMode] = [{m: [], t: []}, ''];
    return linesArray.map(line => {
        var newLines = [];
        if (line === '<<<<<<<' || line === '=======')
            curMode = line === '<<<<<<<'? 'm' : 't';
        else if (line === '>>>>>>>') { 
            newLines = Array.from(mode).map(c => changes[c] || []).flat(1);
            [changes.m, changes.t, curMode] = [[], [], ''];
        } else
            (changes[curMode] || newLines).push(line);
        return newLines;
    }).flat(1);
}
```

#### Solution 3

```
function resolveGitConflict(lines, mode) {
  return lines.reduce((p, c) => {
    let last = p[p.length-1]
    if(typeof last === 'object' ) {
      if(c === '>>>>>>>') last = [].concat(last[mode[0]] || [], last[mode[1]] || [])
      else if(c === '=======') last.t = [] 
      else last[last.t ? 't' : 'm'].push(c)
      return p.slice(0, -1).concat(last)
    } else if(c === '<<<<<<<') c = {m: []}        
    return p.concat(c)
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: "tell which one is better" - what does "better" mean? performance? code readability? ... ?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell "*which one is better*". As Jan mentioned in a comment:

> *"tell which one is better" - what does "better" mean? performance? code readability? ... ?*

The notion of *better* is subjective.

I am drawn to the first solution as it uses the fewest lines, though readability suffers because the lines are quite long and there are nested ternary operators.

I notice **Solution 2** uses ES6 features like arrow functions (as all solutions do) yet it uses the `var` keyword. Some believe there is no use for `var` in modern JS. The variable `newLines` could be declared with `const` if instead of re-assigning it in the `else if` block the length property was set to `0` to truncate it and the mapped values were spread into a call to the `push` method. Using `const` instead of `let` helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).